# Browsers redirecting http to https

Tags: https

I've read a lot of questions and answers about this topic, but nothing I've seen has helped. I have web app with a node/express backend and an aurelia client. It's one of three I have running in the same subdomain. One of the others has a certificate and the other doesn't. Both of them work perfectly. The new app doesn't have a certificate, but it insists on redirecting all requests to https.

In chrome I've deleted the domain security policy and cleared my cache and I get the same result. It doesn't matter which browser I use. I've even tried a browser I've never used to access the app with a certificate and I get the same result.

The server code is essentially the same as for the app which doesn't use a certificate.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Ross

Comment: Maybe its the difference between "essentially the same" and *exactly the same* that is the problem; without seeing *any* code, it would be very hard to say, much less help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The only differences between the two are the express routes and mongoose models. So, I commented those out and still the same error. I contacted some coworkers, in case it was my machine. They get the same error.

Comment: Found the problem. I commented out this code:

app.use(helmet());

and it worked. I'm not sure why this causes a problem here and didn't before, but problem solved.